# bootstrap dropdown open by default

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a login screen, my problem is:
Login screen is bootstrap dropdown. When username password is wrong, page comes with an error message over bootstrap dropdown but since dropdown is closed by default, user cant see it unless points to login part again. I want dropdown login screen open.

Can somebody help me open it by default. may be jquery document ready func. etc.

```
<div class="right-part">
            <div class="log-in-out dropel">
                <a title="Giris" class="icon-login tooltip" id="aH"
                   onclick=" return false;" href="/#">
                    Giris
                    Yap
                </a>

                <div class="dropdown" id="dropdowngiris">
                    <div class="dropdown-wrapper arrow-up-right" id="ddd" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <form name="login-form" id="login-form" action="/Giris"
                      method="post">
                    <p class="login-username">
                        <label for="user_login">Kullanici Adi : </label>
                        <input name="log" class="input" id="user_login" type="text" size="20">
                    </p>
                    <p class="login-password">
                        <label for="user_pass">Sifre : </label>
                        <input name="pwd" class="input" id="user_pass" type="password" size="20">
                    </p>
                    <p class="login-submit">
                        <input name="wp-submit" class="button-primary" id="wp-submit" type="submit" value="Giris">
                        <input name="redirect_to" type="hidden" value="/#">
                    </p>
                </form>
                <p class="login-links clearfix">
                    <span class="fleft">
                        <a title="Sifremi Unuttum"
                           href="/#">
                            Sifrenizi
                            unuttunuz mu?
                        </a>
                    </span>                                                                  <span class="fright">
                        <a href="/#">Kayit Ol</a>
                    </span>
                </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to just trigger a click event on the menu via code after the page has loaded?

Comment: Can you create a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) of this? I'm guessing this is attached to a navbar or something of that sort.

Comment: Yes tried click event but failed

Comment: I couldn't bootply because I couldn't manage css files. But you can see it from http://kuponzan.azurewebsites.net/. Since the requirement is jquery you can try debug from browser I think. If it is needed I can rar and send